# In ultimate frisbee under what circumstances can I catch my own throw?

Tags: ultimate-frisbee

I know that I cant simply throw to myself if I am the thrower. I also know that I can't intentiomally "bounce" the disc of an opponent and catch it. I also know that a team mate may knock it back to me...

However, if the disc hits an opponent is it legal for the thrower to catch the disc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Ultimate Rules](https://usaultimate.org/rules/) list causes for a turnover under rule 13, part D.  One of those is relevant here:

> D.  The following actions result in a turnover and a stoppage of play:
>
> ...
>
> 3. The thrower catches a legally thrown disc. However, it is not a turnover if another player touches the disc during its flight unless the thrower intentionally deflected the disc off another player.

So the rule appears to limit only the intent and not the result.   My interpretation is that if you didn't see an opponent was in the way, or if you tried to throw around but just missed and you were able to grab the deflection, then neither of those should be a turnover.

I am of course assuming that the contact is otherwise normal for a match and not something that could be seen as dangerous play.